# Oracle with IQueryable

Tags: oracle, iqueryable, odp.net

I was having a bit of trouble figuring this out so I thought I'd ask explicity...

Does oracle's ODP.Net or ODT entity framework support IQueyable - ie. If I create simple paging or query in linq will it run the query on the database?

I'm roughly aware that there are commercial products that will work with oracle to do this - I see DevArt pop up quite a bit.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NHibernate to run LINQ queries against Oracle database.

NHibernate uses it's "language" called HQL to talk to various databases. And they also built LINQ provider that creates HQL that is in the second phase sent to target DB.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more searching, it appears the ODP.Net will convert queries into SQL code, but ... poorly on occasion?

see
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2598619

for details & more relevant resources see
https://community.oracle.com/community/developer/english/oracle_database/windows_and_.net/odp.net/content
& enter tag "paging"

According to the last comment in the thread https://community.oracle.com/thread/2349719, linq actully generates the SQL.. interesting